# Random number generation makes the same number everytime

Tags: vb.net

My program generates a random string of 25 characters in length. To do this I have made a List(Of String) with my characters in it and to generate a random character I am using `randomNumber = Int((60 * Rnd() * Rnd()))` this gives me a different character for each entry in the final string but every time the final string is the same. How would I make it so it's not always the same?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim charlist As New List(Of String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim randomNumber As Integer
Dim code1 As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    i = 1
    length = 25
    charlist.Add("a")
    charlist.Add("b")
    charlist.Add("c")
    charlist.Add("d")
    charlist.Add("e")
    charlist.Add("f")
    charlist.Add("g")
    charlist.Add("h")
    charlist.Add("i")
    charlist.Add("j")
    charlist.Add("k")
    charlist.Add("l")
    charlist.Add("m")
    charlist.Add("n")
    charlist.Add("o")
    charlist.Add("p")
    charlist.Add("q")
    charlist.Add("r")
    charlist.Add("s")
    charlist.Add("t")
    charlist.Add("u")
    charlist.Add("v")
    charlist.Add("w")
    charlist.Add("x")
    charlist.Add("y")
    charlist.Add("A")
    charlist.Add("B")
    charlist.Add("C")
    charlist.Add("D")
    charlist.Add("E")
    charlist.Add("F")
    charlist.Add("G")
    charlist.Add("H")
    charlist.Add("I")
    charlist.Add("J")
    charlist.Add("K")
    charlist.Add("L")
    charlist.Add("M")
    charlist.Add("N")
    charlist.Add("O")
    charlist.Add("P")
    charlist.Add("Q")
    charlist.Add("R")
    charlist.Add("S")
    charlist.Add("T")
    charlist.Add("U")
    charlist.Add("V")
    charlist.Add("W")
    charlist.Add("X")
    charlist.Add("Y")
    charlist.Add("Z")
    charlist.Add("0")
    charlist.Add("1")
    charlist.Add("2")
    charlist.Add("3")
    charlist.Add("4")
    charlist.Add("5")
    charlist.Add("6")
    charlist.Add("7")
    charlist.Add("8")
    charlist.Add("9")
    While i < length
        randomNumber = Int((60 * Rnd() * Rnd()))
        code1 = code1 + charlist(randomNumber)
        i = i + 1
    End While
    txtGenerate.Text = code1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: If you're going to use `Rnd` then you need to use `Randomize`. Don't use either though. Create an instance of the `Random` class - ONE instance - and then call `Next` multiple times. You're not writing VB6 code so stop writing VB6 code.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to call `Rnd` (or `random.next`) twice and multiply that, if the intent is an even distribution of the selected characters. That will cause the 'lower' characters in the array to be weighted heavier in the distribution of the final result (that is, a b c will occur more often than 7 8 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Randomize()` before you make a call to `Rnd()`

Example from your code:

```
Randomize()
While i < length
    randomNumber = Int((60 * Rnd() * Rnd()))
    code1 = code1 + charlist(randomNumber)
    i = i + 1
End While
```

From MSDN: [Rnd function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function)

> Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer.

Comment: That code is not quite right because it would mean `Randomize` being called every time the `Button` was clicked when, in fact, it should only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly neater version:

```
Public Module RandomUtils

    Private random As New Random

    Public Function RandomString(length as Integer, Optional chars as String =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") as String

      Return New string(Enumerable.Repeat(1, length).Select(Function(i) chars(random.Next(chars.Length))).ToArray())

    End Function

End Module
```

Use it like this in your form:

```
Dim r as String = RandomUtils.RandomString(25)
```

If you want to vary the characters used, supply a string to the optional parameter:

```
Dim r as String = RandomUtils.RandomString(25, "abc") 'random 25 char string using only a, b or c
```

Beware that it is perfectly possible it will generate curse words, if this string is something the user will see

Comment: Curse words are a feature, not a bug.